# General android programming guide lines

Tags: android, coding-style

I have been programming on android for the past few months and have hit a point where I comprehend the basic ideas and principles for Android development.

Currently I think that my code lacks the appropriate structure and clearance that is required in order for your code to be readable. I know this because sometimes even I find it hard to read my code - and I am not talking about the variable or classes names. I am talking about for example when I open a big ( lengthy ) activity and have 5 overriden methods, 5 more and tons of global variables, a couple of inner-classes and so on it gets hard to find stuff in.

Therefore I have been looking for some guide lines for how to do this so that the code looks good and is readable but I haven't been able to.

There are also small problems to which I find hard to find an answer and usually go with what i feel like rather than knowing for sure what is right in the situation. For example what is better - having the activity implement onClickListener and then having a big switch statement, or just creating new listener for every UI element.

I was hoping some of you might know a place where I can find answers for questions like this. If there is not I will start adding the questions here.

Thank you

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* That said, your example question is probably going to be opinion based as well unless you have a specific problem you're trying to avoid (or a goal to reach) in choosing one or the other.

Comment: This question is pretty broad, because coding style largely depends on the developer's preference. In general, Android follows Java coding standards, with a few additional guidelines for Android specific issues. To address your specific example of onClickListeners, there is no "right" way to do it. You can define them in your xml file, in onCreate, in a separate class...whatever you want and whatever works for you. The question to ask is "is this easily readable." If the answer is "no" for you, then it probably won't be for others as well.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe Yes you are correct. That is why I asked it so that people can send me where they learned how to structure their code, guidelines I should know ... because I have been learning Android by myself and come against stupid little things which experienced people do not even regard as problems. The answers I have had so far are very helpful so my questions is still relevant, at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to learn Android MVP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE4DEwrK2N4

Github link: https://github.com/jpotts18/android-mvp

You can also look at a app that I created which follows mvp structure (well sort of) and with its help, it is easier for me to rollout more features constantly without cluttering my activity/fragment classes. Link: https://github.com/crazyhitty/Munch

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I will read this. That is why I asked this question. So that people can give me links like those.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google's Android Code Style guidelines](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html). It contains some terrific guidelines regarding coding guidelines and style.

Comment: The linked resource contains only hints concerning coding style. This doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @toKrause...That's your interpretation. I eg to differ.

Answer (score 0):

This was written by Chet Haase who works at Google on the Android UI team.

He was input his own and the framework teams knowledge into the articles to clarify the correct Android programming Guidelines.

[Article 1](https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-introduction-5345b451567c#.t0dboklsc)